# How to use Objective C Cocoapods in Swift Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

My swift framework has dependency of Objective C Framework. How do I use that ?

When I try to use Bridging Header, I am getting error like **Framework Target doesn't support Bridging Header**

After my search , I found answers for

1. How to use Objective C Files in Swift Framework
2. How to use Objective C Framework with swift project

But I need solution for

How to use Objective C Framework as dependency in Swift Framework ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Just install the library in the project, then make a Bridging Header and import the header file of that framework in the Bridging Header.

Refer this to create Bridging header [Link](https://mycodetips.com/ios/manually-adding-swift-bridging-header-1290.html)

Comment: This solution is for swift project. I am asking for Swift Framework target.

Answer (score 0):

You should do some silly task and you will be able to add Objective-c Framework as well as Objective-C Files.

1) Create a header file and enter headerFile.

[image]

2) Set Bridging header path like below.

[image]

3) Import Objective-c Framework as well as Objective-C Files like below.

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h>
#import <Google/SignIn.h>
#import "FBFetchUserManager.h"
#import "TGLStackedViewController.h"
```

Comment: We cannot create bridging header for framework target. Above solution will work for App Target